# How can I make the following RegEx pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex pattern.

```
XXX[NUMBER]
```

For Example:
XXX[123456]

or

```
[NUMBER]XXX
```

For Example:
[123456]XXX

What is the pattern to match these two pattern ?

I tried the following way, but I can only add the parentheses to the beginning of the numbers:

```
[\[0-9]{0,35}[X]{0,35}|[X]{0,35}[\[0-9]{0,35}
```

**Kind regards.**

Comment: Use `^(?:X+\[\d+]|\[\d+]X+)$`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for answer. I tried in regex101.com this pattern. Then succeeded. But I use as DevExpress WPF mask. I tried this. Then I have an error. Error Detail: Message=syntax error
InnerException=
StackTrace=   at DevExpress.Data.Mask.RegExpParser.yyerror(String message, String[] expected)

Comment: If you have an error, post the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the numbers with the parenthesis:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\[\d+\]");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the alternative answer that can be used on the DevExpress side for my question.

**Here is the answer:**

```
[\[0-9\]]{0,35}[X]{0,35}|[X]{0,35}[\[0-9\]]{0,35}
```

Thanks to everyone who replied.